# Loading Jquery on lightbox page

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I want to load a javascript code once a lightbox is loaded.
Please explain the event that should be used.

```
<script>
 $j(function() {
 alert("hello");
});
</script>

<a href="#generated-code" data-toggle="lightbox">SHOW CODE</a>                  
<div id="generated-code" class="lightbox hide fade" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="container-fluid">            
<div class="lightbox-content"> 
   <textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="6" cols="50">Sample text</textarea>
   <p><input type="button" id="copy" name="copy" value="Copy" /></p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The above script executes on page load and not when I click the copy button inside lightbox.I want to execute the script on copy button click, but even if I use click event with jquery it does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If possible post your code that loads the light box here, Any way without seeing your code what i can say is the simplest one , just give your javascript code after the line of code that loads the light box.

Answer (score 0):

To execute script on the click of the copy button you can use the below code

```
 $j(function() {
    $j("#copy").click(function(){
           // place your code here

    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But my problem is that I am running a copy clipboard javascript inside the function which does not seem to execute.